# C++ style commenting style in css

Tags: css

I designing a webkit based web application and i am generating my css using c++ and so naturally i am on a c++ ide.My finished css file looks like

```
/**
Css Modules and Sub Modules Table Of Content
 */

responsiveGrid();
resets();

/**
 * @brief responsiveGrid
 * @return
 */
function responsiveGrid(){}
.container{}
/**
 * @brief resets
 * @return
 */
function resets(){}
.tableView{}
```

Function definitions shall be deleted and so are the function implementations leaving me with the comments and the clean crisp css code.My problem is with the comments.Will this type of commenting allowed in `css3` or `css2`?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have figured this out yourself by simply checking the official CSS specifications. [The CSS2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) says in [the section on comments](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#comments)

> Comments begin with the characters `"/*"` and end with the characters
>   `"*/"`. They may occur anywhere outside other tokens, and their contents
>   have no influence on the rendering. Comments may not be nested.

The CSS3 specification [has no module covering syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/#css3), so the CSS2 rules apply.

Comment: I did look there but i was not sure if my type of comment exactly as is would pass that requirement.

Comment: Well, there is a near-decade-old [Syntax module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax), but it's safe to say that document is non-canon as it's pending a rewrite. That said, comments are not expected to change in syntax or semantics in CSS3.

Comment: @JesusWithIssues Not sure what part of the specification was unclear as it applied to your comments. Was it the "begin with... and end with..." part? Was it the "outside other tokens" part? Was it the "may not be nested" part?

Comment: The "Comments may not be nested" part and "They may occur anywhere outside other tokens" part.

Comment: "Comments may not be nested" means that you cannot put a comment inside a comment. "The may occur anywhere outside other tokens" means that they cannot be inserted into the middle of a token. For example `block/* comment */quote` is not a legal place for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Sure they're allowed as comments as long as they start with `/*` and end with `*/`. They just have the same meaning as any other comment in CSS: none whatsoever.

By the way, these are C-style comments, not C++-style. C++ single-line comments begin with `//`, have no end marker, and are not valid CSS.